# TFS API unable to get any version information

Tags: c#

When I do `RegisteredTfsConnections.GetProjectCollections()` I only get one collection when I have several.

When I query this collection for changes I am unable to get any results.

My code:

```
var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(_registeredProjectCollections[0]);

var vcs = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var cs = vcs.QueryHistory(@"$/MyCollection", RecursionType.Full);
```

Instead of $/MyCollection I have tried lots of variations. The result is always that I get an empty collection back from QueryHistory.

I cannot find any documentation anywhere that explains in more detail how to set up a connection and start querying, the MSDN is fairly useless. If anyone can explain what I am doing wrong it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question: how to get the list of Collections or the History in TFVC?

Comment: I am trying to get a list of checkins but I get nothing back when I am expecting something back. So I wonder if I have the syntax or path wrong, or if I need to do something else.

Comment: Could be something as simple that you use the Collection name instead of a Project name? In TFS Collection = Database and TFVC is scoped to a DB, so $/ is everything inside a Collection, $/MyProject filters a TeamProject belonging to current collection